# orient 2 points to another 2 points

Tags: objects, edit-mode, vertices, transform-orientation

Please, Is there a way to orient 2 vertices of one object, to another 2 vertices of another object? For example I need to move and rotate in one step -  prism with vertices A,B to the prism with vertices C,D . Point A will be on the point C and point B on the D. I want make same direction and position in one command. Is there something in blender ?

Here it is a better example. I want to copy couple of objects from point A,B to C,D. I need to move them to exact position with exactly same rotation to the slab. Thank you!

[image]

[image]